# Visual Studio Code - Include context in search results

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to show context for search results in Visual Studio Code?

By default, if I search "debug" for example I might get 2 lines of code returned.

```
filea.rb
  def debug(str)
fileb.js
  function debug(str) {
```

I want to see what the code is for, say, 3 lines above and below each match.

```
filea.rb
  def somefunca
    puts "some func a"
  end

  def debug(str)
    puts str.inspect
  end

  def somefuncb
```

Is it possible to add context like this to the search results?

Comment: Visual Studio Code search feature is kind of weird. For instance, it's possibly the only editor where you can't keep search results if you need to do a second search. I'm sure it'll be improved in the future but, for now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

v1.41 is adding a preview of a feature which will display search results in an editor thus allowing for some context lines around the actual search result.  See `search.enableSearchEditorPreview`

> **Preview: Search Editor**
>
> In this milestone, we've started work on showing the results of a
> search in an editor. This provides much more space to view search
> results and allows users to maintain multiple collections of search
> results simultaneously. With this release, in a search editor you can:
>
> - Navigate to results using Go to Definition-family commands, including Peek Definition and Open Definition to Side.
> - Rerun a search to update the list of results
> - View lines of context surrounding a result
> - Persist results to disk to be referenced later or even tracked in SCM
>
> We will be continuing to add functionality and increase usability in
> the coming releases.
>
> Note: You can preview this feature by enabling the setting
> `search.enableSearchEditorPreview`**strong text**.

[image: preview search in an editor demo]

---

**v1.42** is adding a bit more functionality, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#search-editor.  Like selecting the context width around the search result and running another search right in the search editor itself.

[image: search context demo]

---

By the way, you can directly open a search editor without first doing a search in the panel with the command `New Search Editor` (`search.action.openNewEditor`) currently unbound (and renamed in v1.48).  That command will always open a new Search Editor.

If instead, you wish to **re-use a Search Editor** (rather than opening a new one), a command is being **added to v1.48**:

`Open Search Editor`  :  `search.action.openEditor` // also unbound by default

---

**v1.43** release notes https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_search-editors

> In a search editor, results can be navigated to using "Go to
> Definition" actions, such as kb(`editor.action.revealDefinition`) to
> open the source location in the current editor group, or
> kb(`editor.action.revealDefinitionAside`) to open the location in an editor to
> the side. Additionally, double clicking can optionally open the source
> location, configurable with the
> `search.searchEditor.doubleClickBehaviour` setting.

[image: search editor image]

> You can open a new search editor with the Search Editor: Open New
> Search Editor command, or using the "Open New Search Editor" button at
> the top of the search viewlet. Alternatively, you can copy your
> existing results from a search viewlet search over to a search editor
> with the "Open in Editor" link added to the top of the results tree,
> or the Search Editor: Open Reuslts in Editor command.
>
> Note You can try out the experimental Search Editor: Apply Changes
> extension to synchronize edits you make in a search editor back to
> source files:

[image: search and apply changes]

------------------------------- see edit below:

Showing the context lines does not appear to be persistent between uses of the search editor.  But <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> acts as a **toggle** to show/hide the context.  The value chosen for the number of context lines is persistent.

However, in v1.44 and the Insiders' Build are two new commands fro increasing/decreasing the number of context lines surrounding each search result:

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",
  "command": "decreaseSearchEditorContextLines",
  "when": "inSearchEditor"
},
{
  "key": "alt+=",
  "command": "increaseSearchEditorContextLines",
  "when": "inSearchEditor"
}
```

They are unbound by default - these are just sample keybindings.  The context lines input box does not need to be visible for these to work.  So <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to enable context lines or these new commands to change the number.

---

In v1.46 there is a new setting to make the **amount of context lines shown persistent**:

```
 "search.searchEditor.defaultNumberOfContextLines": 4,  // default is now 1
```

and

`search.searchEditor.reusePriorSearchConfiguration` - Reuse the last active search editor's configuration when creating a new search editor

(`defaultNumberOfContextLines` seems to take precedence over `reusePriorSearchConfiguration`)

See [v1.46 release notes: Search Editor improvements](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#search-editor)

Comment: Mark, do you know if it's possible to always show the context with the new search editor? It seems like I have to click on "Show Context" every time, and it doesn't remember my choice.

Comment: @freeall No, it doesn't look like it will remember being enabled.  I added an edit to the end of my answer about this - there is a toggle available.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the command! Annoying it doesn't remember it.

Comment: @freeall Looks like a persistent context line setting is coming in v1.46.

Answer (score 2):

You can single click the results which will open the relevant code in a "preview" editor. With the preview you can navigate the results list (clicking, <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+n</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl+p</kbd>) without opening new editors.

But it sounds like you want to avoid the preview altogether. In that case, [here's a feature request](http://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28941), but it looks like it was closed prematurely and needs to be submitted again. The only solution that was actually implemented was a setting for placing the search results in the panel, rather than the sidebar: `"search.location": "panel"`.

Comment: I did find the search location setting, which has helped. I did not realize there was a preview, and being able to scroll through that will help. Not the same as context, but better than nothing. Thank you.