# Multiple search windows in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have multiple searches in Visual Studio Code?

To search on:

- `term A` have the results in one search window
- and then search on `term B` and have the results in another window

and always have these two windows visible (like in Visual Studio).

Comment: You can now create as many search editors as you like (in early 2020). See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_search-editors and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230054/836330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16488) on the GitHub repo, and is on the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#workbench) for 2019.

Comment: Well, it's still showing on the 2020 Roadmap (made at the end of 1019) but the legend says this is completed (has a checkmark, not a bullet, running guy, etc.) but I still can't figure out how to do this, and found my question already asked here.  "Find Refs" must be considered a separate feature from "Search"?

Answer (score 26):

Here's how do to this currently VSCode(1.51.0):

1. Open the search panel on the left
2. On the top there is a + Document icon (second from the right)

[image]

3. Click this - it will open a search window as a editor tab.

Comment: almost perfect, if it could use the search panel to display results instead of opening an editor. I really like the old visual studio search 'result 1', 'result 2' ...tabs. oh well.

Comment: You can add a Keyboard Shortcut (Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts) for the action `search.action.openNewEditor` (e.g. `ALT + F`) instead of doing this manually.