# Show Full Line in Search Results

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code / vscode, when I search for something, the beginning of the line in each search result may be cut off. How do I see the cut off part?

For example, say I search for `'directory'`, a search result may show this:

```
require('../../../directory');
```

while the actual, full line is this:

```
var directory = require('../../../directory');
```

How do I get vscode to display the full line (second example)?

If this has been asked before, I cannot find it. If anyone else can, feel free to mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I think the only way is to search for the regex '.*directory.*'  It is a pain but appears to do what you want - show the whole line.

Answer (score -1):

See [Visual Studio Code - Include context in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599104/visual-studio-code-include-context-in-search-results/59230054#59230054) for info about a preview of showing search results in an editor - which includes the ability to display the full line and more context around search results.

Comment: The linked post doesn't answer how to display the full line in the search results, and your present answer isn't very helpful.  Can you please add some additional details to enable showing the full line in the search results?