# Visual Studio Code search not showing entire line

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO8Sa.jpg)Visual Studio Code, when I do a search and find mutiple items, it does not show the entire line of code/text in the search return results.  It only seems to show a set number of characters.

How do I make is show the entire line in the results.

Update:  It seems to not show the first 11 characters of the line

Comment: I think the only way is to search for a regex of the line.  Something like .*yourSearchTerm.* it is a pain but it works.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488545/show-full-line-in-search-results?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599104/visual-studio-code-include-context-in-search-results/59230054#59230054

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 'Find in Files' (ctrl+shift+f) instead of 'Find' (ctrl+f).

Comment: I am using the ctrl+shift+f method.  Trying to figure out how to post a screenshot

Comment: screenshot of issue posted in main post