# VS Code search results is not showing the leading portion of the line for some hits

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, line

A search for "TESTADDR" produces these as the results:

> TESTADDR DC F'0'
> L R2,TESTADDR
> READ DECB,SF,DCB,TESTADDR,LENGTH

The third result line is actually:   "*    READ DECB, ..."
"TESTADDR" resides in column 1.
"L" resides in column 10.

"Open in editor" reveals the full line of data, as another Q&A had suggested, but the search results are the issue.
Is there a setting that effects this?
My goal is to see the full line from the file(s).

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and edit it into your post. Also, what other post are you talking about?

Comment: I don' think there is any option to show the entire line in the search view results.  Other than in a search editor as you know.

Comment: The other posts are: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616153/visual-studio-code-search-not-showing-entire-line

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488545/show-full-line-in-search-results?noredirect=1&lq=1