# How to exclude duplicate lines in VS Code's search results?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I do a search in VS Code, it will return the same line multiple times if the search string is found in a line multiple times. For example, if I search for "`Automobile`", the following line will show up twice in the search results:

```
var myAutomobile = 'Ford Automobile';
```

Is there any way to get VS Code to display the same line only once?

(I know that I can manually remove a line from the search results by clicking the 'x' on the right-hand  side, but I'm wondering if there's an automated way to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

This does happen in the search panel results (and I don't think can be avoided) but if you enable this setting:

`search.enableSearchEditorPreview` (or search for "Search: Enable Search Editor Preview" in the settings)

and then click on the "`open in editor`" link at the top of the search results (after a new search after enabling the setting), a new editor tab will open with your search results and I don't see duplicates listed there.

More info: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#search-editor and [Visual Studio Code - Include context in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599104/visual-studio-code-include-context-in-search-results/59230054#59230054)

[image: search preview]

And in v1.42 (coming later this week) you can use this command `search.action.openNewEditor` to directly open a search editor without first executing a search in the traditional panel.

Comment: Thanks, but the search results in the new window aren't hyperlinks.  

I submitted a feature request to Microsoft:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90033

Comment: They are links if you Ctrl+click.

Comment: Too bad that the original request (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90033 ) was closed - I had exactly the same problem and I think this "known limitation of the search viewlet" should be fixed!