# How to remove irrelevant lines when opening search result in editor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I press `Ctrl + Shift + F` to search across files. The result appears on the side bar and I want to open it in an editor. However, the result in the editor displays some irrelevant lines to my search, how should I remove them?

In my case, I want to display 5 lines only (14, 25, 27, 38, 41) in the editor.

[image]

Comment: related: [Visual Studio Code - Include context in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51599104/11107541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to filter context lines (Toggle Contex Lines) on the right side of the search box or you can use the shortcut key combination as (Alt+L).

[image]