# visual-studio-code does it have equivant to slick edit selective display

Tags: visual-studio-code, slickedit

I am a new Code user but previously used SlickEdit

One Slickedit function that I used was the Selective Display function which allowed you to only see the lines that match a search (or alternatively hide matched lines)

Does Code have any equivalent function?

I know I can use Fold to hide procedure bodies but I haven't found anything like the SlickEdit function yet

Update:
I have now created feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200997
Please give it a thumbs up if you would like to see Selective Display function in vsCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an exact-match feature.

As a workaround, you can use a [Search Editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor), expand the search options (three dot menu button to the right) and put the path to the file of interest in "files to include", and [toggle context lines off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69431188/11107541).

Editing in the search editor won't reflect in the actual file though (but you can double-click a line to jump to the line in an editor tab for the actual file).

For negative matching / exclusion, see [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/11107541). TL;DR turn on regex mode and use the form `^((?!foo).)*$`.

<s>If you want a dedicated feature, then you can [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).</s> The asker has now create an issue ticket: [Create a selective display facility equivant to slick edit selective display #200997](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200997). If you are reading and would like this feature, I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions,  The Search editor does a lot of what I want though it doesn't have the option to unfold/refold the hidden lines or the ability to show multiple searches though I suppose that could be done via regex expression.

I feel all of the facilities needed for selective display exist within Code but just haven't been put together (yet).   A pity since it was available in main frame editors like ISPF and Xedit 30 or more years ago!